# Nikon Lens Warranty explanation

Tags: lens, nikon, equipment-protection, maintenance

I want to purchase a good lens of about $1K from Nikon (the 18-300mm lens for example) and I have a few quick questions about the Nikon Lens warranty. I researched online extensively and it seems there are no conclusive answers. Your help would be greatly appreciated

1. How long is the warranty? What is the difference between the first year and 5 year warranty? And all you have to do to enrol into the 5 year warranty is to send in some paperwork within a certain time?
2. Assuming you are on the first year warranty and your autofocus stops working on the lens. How much do you have to pay for the repair assuming it costs Nikon $500 to repair it for you? Zero? Is there a max deductible you pay? And then if you are at year 4 (now within the domain of the 5-year warranty period), how much would you have to pay for the repair?
3. What advantage is there to buy the Squaretrade or Mack warranty if Nikon already provides warranty?
4. Which warranty is best of Nikon lens in terms of zero-worrry for drop/spill and maybe even theft/loss irrespective of cost?

Thank you and hope these are not too many questions. I thought they were related enough to combine them into one question.

Comment: If you paid for the lens with a credit card, check to see if the issuer offers loss/damage coverage for things purchased with it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nikon cameras and lenses are covered by a 1 year warranty.  Lenses have a 4 year extension of that warranty.  If you have an issue under warranty it doesn't matter if it's in the 1st year or the 5th, the coverage will be the same.

If a lens is repaired under warranty, there will be no charge for the repair - you will have to cover the cost of shipping the lens to the repair centre if you cannot drop it off.

Nikon's warranty only covers defects, but doesn't cover damage you've caused, like dropping the lens or getting it wet.  Some Squaretrade and Mack warranties will cover accidental damage. They do not cover theft or loss.

I don't know who carries out the actual repairs for Squaretrade and Mack.  I would be concerned about having gear handled by someone other than an authorised Nikon repairer, so you might want to ask them what their expertise is with Nikon gear.

I couldn't advise on what is best for drop/spill or theft/loss.  If you have home/contents insurance, that is likely the least expensive option - depending on the cost of your gear it might be covered with no additional premium.  I believe my contents insurance covers up to $1500 without needing to itemise it and pay an extra premium.  There would be an excess (deductable) on contents insurance though, while SquareTrade/Mack would pay out the full amount.

I think paying $200-300 for a few years of coverage on a $1000 lens which already has a 5 year warranty by the manufacturer, and which is probably covered by homeowners insurance for theft and even droppage, is probably not a worthwhile investment.

Comment: Thank you, this answer helps a lot. I will look into homeowner's insurance !